# Bootstrap 4 accordian with ngFor in angular4?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, accordion

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" *ngFor="customeOffer of customOfferData">
        <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                 {{customeOffer.name}}
               </h5>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

My accordian with ngFor is not working .It is giving error.Can anyone tell me.Please help .Thank in advance.

Comment: post your error

Comment: You are missing many things which are required for Bootstrap4 accordion. Please check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of ngFor loop is 
*ngFor ="let variable of array".

So in your case,the syntax will be like this:

```
*ngFor="let customeOffer of customOfferData"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, your `ngFor` is not working, and if you are getting this error,

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known
>   property of `element`

The issue is: `*ngFor="customeOffer of customOfferData"`

You missed `let` keyword `*ngFor="let customeOffer of customOfferData"`

Reference: [Showing an array property with *ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4